# Object rotation is not correct when rotating the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, raycasting

I have a camera which is showing the userInterface (canvas) object into the front of my camera. **I am only updating my userinterface position if the camera raycast is not hitting my userInterface object collider**. something like this

```
public class UIPlacerAtCamFront : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject userInterface;
    public float placementDistance;
    Vector3 uiPlacementPosition;
    RaycastHit  objectHit; 

    void Update () {

        Vector3 fwd = this.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        //Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, fwd * 50, Color.green);

        if (Physics.Raycast(this.transform.position, fwd, out objectHit, 50))
        {
            //raycast hitting the userInterface collider, so do nothing, userinterface is infornt of the camrea already
        }
        else
        {
            //raycast is not hitting userInterfae collider, so update UserInterface position accoding to the camera
            uiPlacementPosition = this.transform.position + this.transform.forward * placementDistance;
            userInterface.transform.position = uiPlacementPosition;
        }

        //Continuously update userInterface rotation according to camera
        userInterface.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation; 
    }
}
```

The above script has attached with my camera, it displaying the object correctly but as i start to rotate my camera my UI object rotation looks very strange as below image suggested
[image: This is inital correct rotation]

As i rotate, this problem occurs
[image]

I know that the problem is in rotation, so I tired to change my this rotation code

```
    userInterface.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;
```

to this

```
userInterface.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (this.transform.localEulerAngles.x,
            0,
            this.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
```

but it bring another strange rotation for me, like given below
[image]

I want that my userinteface object face my camera correclty, even my camera watching the start or end of my userinteface object. How can i rotate my UI according to camera rotation correctly?

Comment: I'd recommend setting render mode on your canvas to `Screen Space - Overlay`.

Comment: I am unsure what the desired behavior would be (on that second image). Would you mind elaborating it a little?

Also... if you are having trouble with euler angles try `Quaternion.LookAt()`, I find it more intuitive and bullet-proof.

Comment: @lggy i can't make it screen space

Comment: i am making some selection on canvas with camera pointer that why i can't set canvas to screen space. The camera pointer will rotate according to camera and it will make selection from world space UI.

Comment: @MaglethongSpirr i want that it rotate but at specific distance. when my camera looks start or end of the canvas(user inteface) object it become appear very near to my camera as image 2 suggested. And when i fixed my y movement it showing very far(rotation) from camera as image 3rd suggested

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly. You want a behavior similar to sliding google maps. Only that the camera has to rotate and the picture has to adjust its position and rotation for the behavior.

The following code should do that:

```
void Update() {
    userInterface.transform.rotation = this.transform.rotation;

    // Project camera to canvas plane
    Vector3 projection = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(this.transform.position - userInterface.transform.position, userInterface.transform.forward)
        + userInterface.transform.position;

    // Get distance from camera to projected position (basically, distance from point to plane)
    float curDistance = (this.transform.position - projection).magnitude;

    // Correct that distance with desired distance
    userInterface.transform.position += this.transform.forward * (placementDistance - curDistance);
}
```

Comment: i only want to update the user interface position if the raycast is not hitting the userinteface. because i am making some selection from my camera on to user interface

Comment: camera contain a child pointer that select different objects on userinterface and it rotates to do selection at different location of the canvas. if i update all the time position as your code suggested i will unable to select it

Comment: You could save rotations instead of positions. Or you could use a second camera rendering the ui on top with a planar logic, but I do not see how it could be possible to keep a constant minimum distance to a rotating object without displacing it a little.

Comment: transform.position assign attempt for 'Canvas' is not valid. Input position is { Infinity, NaN, Infinity }.
UnityEngine.Transform:set_position(Vector3)
UIPlacerAtCamFront:Update() (at Assets/UIPlacerAtCamFront.cs:42)

Comment: displace a little to adjust but you code doesnt seems that doing

Comment: As you can check i am raycasting where to place that little displacement code